# package.preload alternative in Lua?

Tags: c++, lua

I learned that `package.preload` can be used to expose a script to other scripts.

Here's my example code.

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
lua_settop(L, 0);
//Script A
luaL_dostring(L, "local A = {} package.preload['A'] = function () return A end A.num = 3"); 
//Script B
luaL_dostring(L, "local A = require 'A' print(A.num)"); 
lua_close(L);
```

The result: `3`

Although this works fine, I wonder if Script `A`'s code can be more simplified or if there's other alternative solution to expose  a script to other scripts.

ADDED: The main reason I'm asking this is because I think `package.preload['A'] = function () return A end` is quite long and boring to write.

Comment: *if there's other alternative solution to expose a script to other scripts.* - Yes, you could simply allow the 2nd script to import your stuff.

Comment: It's not clear what your real problem is here. Do you have files you want to load as modules, or strings in your program you want to load as modules, or strings from some other source you want to load as modules? What is your goal here, exactly?

Comment: @NicolBolas I want to load scripts as strings and be able to expose one to another by using `require`. I just want to know if there's any simpler solution than mine.

Comment: @ZackLee: So the strings in question are hard-coded into your executable, yes? They're not being loaded from a file based on the module name or something.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes. they are not being loaded from a file.

Comment: When asking about the C-API you should also tag either [[tag:c]] **or** [[tag:c++]] depending on which language you are using the API from.  I know from your previous questions that you use C++ but others don't.  I retagged your question accordingly.

Comment: @HenriMenke I think I forgot it this time. Thank you for editing it Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you want to prefix `local A = {} package.preload['A'] = function () return A end` to every chunk defining a module (where `A` is the module name).  I think it would be much easier to just use string concatenation for that.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <lua.hpp>

int preload(lua_State *L, std::string const &modname,
            std::string const &modcode) {
    std::string code = "package.preload['" + modname + "'] = function()\n" +
                       "local " + modname + " = {}\n" + modcode + "\n"
                       "return " + modname + " end";
    return luaL_dostring(L, code.c_str());
}

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    // Script A
    preload(L, "A", "A.num = 3");
    // Script B
    luaL_dostring(L, "local A = require 'A' print(A.num)");
    lua_close(L);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I think this is simple and brilliant solution. I will give you a bounty.

Comment: @Henri: That doesn't do things correctly. By putting the code for the module *outside* of the loader function (the function stored in the `preload` table), when you execute `preload`, it will already have built the module itself. Building the module is something that should be done when the module is loaded via a `require` call. That's why the `preload` loader is a function, not merely a table containing a previously loaded module. If you want that, just modify the `package.loaded` table *directly*.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, where you have some set of in-C strings that represent Lua modules, `package.preload` is exactly the tool to use. Though your specific use of it leaves something to be desired.

Generally speaking, the modules themselves do not define their names. So hard-coding the module's name into the string is not the correct move. Similarly, modules do not register themselves; they should be registered by the environment around the module.

What you really want is to take an array of name+Lua code strings and register them as module preloads in a loop. So you'd have something like this. I'll be using Lua 5.3; you can translate it to older version of Lua pretty easily.

Also, be warned: this code is untested.

```c
const char *lua_preloads[] =
{
    "A", "local A = {}\n"
        "A.num = 3\n"
        "return A)\n", //Modules are usually tables, not functions.
    ...
    NULL //Null-terminated list.
};

//Loader function
int lua_preloader_func(lua_State *L)
{
    int nargs = lua_gettop(L);
    int lua_func_ix = lua_upvalueindex(1);
    lua_pushvalue(L, lua_func_ix);

    //Move the function to the bottom of the stack
    lua_insert(lua_func_ix, 1);

    //Call with all of the given arguments.
    lua_call(L, nargs, LUA_MULTRET);
    return lua_gettop(L);
}

int top = lua_gettop(L);

//Get the package.preload table.
lua_getglobal(L, "package");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "preload");
int preload_ix = lua_gettop();

for(const char **position = lua_preloads;
    *position;
    position += 2)
{
    const char *module_name = position[0];
    const char *module = position[1];

    //Compile the preload script into a Lua function.
    int err = luaL_loadbufferx(L, module, strlen(module), module_name, "t");

    //Check for errors in `err`.

    //Create a Lua C-function with the script as an upvalue.
    lua_pushcclosure(L, lua_preloader_func, 1);

    //Stick that Lua C-function inside of package.preload[preload.first].
    lua_setfield(L, preload_ix, module_name);
}

lua_settop(L, top);
```

Comment: I tried your code but couldn't even compile it. And I honestly don't understand how to make use of this. I would appreciate if you post an example that actually works.

Comment: Firstly, I get `Excess elements in scalar initializer` in `**lua_preloads` and `Use of undeclared identifier `preload_ix`.

Comment: I just edited my question. I would appreciate if you could show me creating a function like `createLocalTable`.

Comment: @ZackLee: "*couldn't even compile it*" That's what "untested" means. I've since eliminated the blatant grammatical failures, but I still haven't actually hooked it up to Lua and tested it.

Comment: Thank you. One more quesiton: what should be `preload_ix`?